# Unable to load JavaScript and got pyppeteer error from webpage with requests

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, python-requests-html, pyppeteer

I'm trying to scrape a webpage after login.

If I use only BeautifulSoup and requests I get

> Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application.

So, I decided to use `html_requests` with the following code:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()

session.get(url)
session.post(loginUrl, data = {"email":"email@gmail.com", "password": "Pass123"})


resp.html.render()
```

But I get the same error or:

> pyppeteer.errors.PageError: net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

So I decided to use selenium, even though I really prefer to use request due to higher script speed.

When I use selenium, it works fine, but when I load the selenium's page source into BeautifulSoup, I again get the

> Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application.

error page.

Why? On driver is loaded fine and I just parse the HTML page from selenium.

How can I fix both the `requests_html` and `BeautifulSoup` errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need either pyppeteer or selenium. You can log in using a plain `request` and get all the data you want.

The key here is to get the `accessToken` via the `Login` endpoint and then use it in subsequent requests.

The API calls I'm making here are the *meat* of the page *after* logging in. The rest of the HTML is just eye-candy. The data coming from the API corresponds to what you see on the site:

[image]

As for the `pyppeteer.errors.PageError: net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`, this error is typically caused by an SSL/TLS handshake failure. The server you're trying to connect to may be using an outdated or unsupported SSL/TLS version or cipher suite.

You can read more about the error [here](https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/troubleshooting/version-cipher-mismatch/).

**TL;DR:** There's not much *you* can do about it.

I'd recommend using my approach (no browser, just API calls).

Benefits of the following approach:

- lightweight
- relatively fast
- no SSL errors
- full data

Here's how you can get the sale data:

```py
import requests
from dateutil.parser import parse

login_url = "https://api-it.saywow.me/it-it/api/Users/Login"
sales_url = "https://api-it.saywow.me/it-it/api/Booking/GetCanBookSaleEvents"
payload = {
    "email": "YOUR_EMAIL",
    "password": "YOUR_PASSWORD",
}


def format_date(date: str) -> str:
    return parse(date).strftime("%d %B")


def show_sales(sales_data: list) -> None:
    for sale in sales_data:
        event = sale["saleEvent"]["saleEventName"]
        address = sale["saleEvent"]["addressFull"]
        start_date = format_date(sale["saleEvent"]["startDate"])
        end_date = format_date(sale["saleEvent"]["endDate"])
        is_booked = sale["isBooked"]

        template = f"""
Event: {event}
Address: {address}
Dates: {start_date} - {end_date}
Booked: {"Yes!" if is_booked else "You can book this event!"}
"""
        print(template)


def main() -> None:
    with requests.Session() as session:
        response = session.post(login_url, json=payload)
        token = response.json()["data"]["accessToken"]
        sales = session.post(
            sales_url,
            headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"},
        )
        show_sales(sales.json()["data"])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If you plug in your registration email and a valid password, you should see this:

```
Event: HOUSE OF LUXURY
Address: Viale John Fitzgerald Kennedy 54, Napoli NA
Dates: 08 December - 17 December
Booked: You can book this event!


Event: Monot Archive Sale
Address: Via Orobia 11, Milano MI
Dates: 28 November - 06 December
Booked: You can book this event!
```

There's plenty more in the `sales_data` table, like location, phone numbers, etc.

Here's a sample:

```json
...

"addressName": "Via Orobia",
"addressNumber": "11",
"addressCity": "Milano",
"addressProvince": "MI",
"addressZip": "20139",
"addressCountry": "IT",
"addressLat": 45.4426322,
"addressLon": 9.2056631,

...
```

Comment: I just observed the traffic in the Network tab of my browser's DevTools.

Comment: is there any way to get html of the sales page? In order to scrape more data

Comment: Yes, I believe so, but that would make a new question, as this is out of scope for this one. Also, if you find my answer useful, please consider upvoting and/or accepting it.

Comment: yes sure, but as stated I want to scrape the whole webpage after loggin, and also I still can't figure out why when I pass the html page from selenium to BeautifulSoup it gets me error eventhough on driver is loaded fine

Comment: I don't think there's much you can do about the SSL error. This error is typically caused by an SSL/TLS handshake failure. The server you're trying to connect to may be using an outdated or unsupported SSL/TLS version or cipher suite. As for the *whole webpage after login*, well, the *meat* comes from the API call, the rest of the HTML is just eye-candy.